# Is true that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}\sin(n x)$ converges pointwise on $[0,2\pi]$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

> Let $(a_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}^{2}<\infty.$ Is true that the series
> \begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}\sin(n x)
> \end{align}
> converges pointwise on $[0,2\pi]$ ?

The Dirichlet test fails to conclude as $a_{n}$ may not be monotone. So how can I proceed ? Are there any suggestions of this problem ? I will be appreciated.

Comment: You should take a look at Carleson’s theorem: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem. In a nutshell: this problem is really hard, the simplest solution is already quite involved and conceptually complex in harmonic analysis. But well, the answer to your question is yes, the series converges pointwise.

Comment: Actually, Carleson's theorem shows the convergence ae; it is a standard result that something like $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{\sin 10^n x}{n}$ fails to converge on an everywhere dense set of the second category (and zero measure of course) in $[0, 2\pi]$

Comment: Sorry guys, I still cannot see why this question has anything to do with Carleson's theorem, can someone else explain?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}\sin(n x)$ is a Fourier series in $L^2$ (of an unique in the $L^2$ sense odd function in $[-\pi,\pi]$ - by periodicity this gives the condition $f(2\pi-x)=-f(x), x \in [0, 2\pi]$ if you want to rather have $x \in [0, 2\pi]$) - by the condition $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}^{2}<\infty$; note that the example above gives such a function that diverges on fairly large set in a category sense (everywhere dense, second category) though it is still of measure zero; Carleson theorem insures the result (converges ae) holds for any $a_n, \sum a_n^2 < \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\sin(5^k \pi/2) = 1$ for all positive integers $k$, so e.g.
$\sum_{n} a_n \sin(n\pi/2)$ diverges to $+\infty$ where
$$ a_n = \cases{1/k & if $n = 5^k$ for some positive integer $k$\cr
                 0 & otherwise}$$

Comment: it is easy to show that $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{sin 5^n x}{n}$ has unbounded partial sums on an everywhere dense set (which is also of the second category - general result about points of divergence of sequences of continuous functions ) - if for example the partial sums would be bounded on an interval $I$, one can construct inductively closed subintervals $I_n \subset I_{n-1} ...\subset I$ on which $\sin 5^kx \ge 1/2, k=m, m+1,..m+n-1$ for a fixed $m$ large enough to start the induction, and then at an intersection point of such, one would get the contradiction that $\sum 1/n < \infty$